# GtkDialog in shell

Tags: linux, user-interface, shell, gtk

I'm using gtkdialog in shell script but I got stuck.I tried "use-markup" to format the font,however it appears does not work.Is not there anything like ?
And if the program has several widgets the layout always be disorderly...
Is there a solution?Or a good tutorial on gtkdialog?(I searched but could not find one besides the user-manual).
EDIT:I'm trying to change the font ,color it.The problem with desordely layout I've solved.

Comment: can you give us sample code and tell us exactly what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

use-markup means that text will be styled using the [Pango Text Attribute Markup Language](http://library.gnome.org/devel/pango/stable/PangoMarkupFormat.html). You'll have to markup your text accordingly to get the desired font/style/color/etc.